# Output datestring in specified format

Tags: javascript, string, date

I have seen a lot of posts about parsing strings into dates, but not such definitive answers about the other direction, dates into strings of the desired format.

I have a Javascript `Date` (which I made from `Date(unixtimestamp)`) and I want a string that looks like `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'`. Sure, I could get year, month, day, hour, and min and manually make the string with the dashes and colon, but that's multiple lines where I wonder if a single line of someone else's code will do.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the only way you'll get a single line of code is using a library, like moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: You could just write a function...and use the function everywhere, then it will be one line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.toISOString returns almost what you want.

```
var d= new Date();
var s= d.toISOString();
```

/*  returned value: (String) 2014-07-28T18:26:46.550Z */

You can tinker with the return in the same line of code-

```
var d= new Date();
var s= d.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').slice(0, 16);
```

/*  returned value: (String) 2014-07-28 18:26 */

or even:

```
(new Date(1406571989450)).toISOString().replace('T', ' ').slice(0, 16);
```

/*  returned value: (String) 2014-07-28 18:26 */

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is this in UTC or my local timezone? (I'd rather UTC.)

Comment: the 'Z' in the complete return means UTC (ZULU timezone, in military parlance)